# Bash profile corrupted: unable to open bash

Tags: macos

I am unable to open `.bash_profile` on mac terminal, because by mistake i have set the wrong path. Could any one please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: See: [How to reset Bash on Mac OSX, .bash\_profile corrupted and bash no longer works](http://superuser.com/q/498312)

Answer (score 0):

Just reset your path using:

```
export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Ho‌​me/bin:/Users/qsgte‌​chnologies/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/qsgtech‌​nologies/Library/Andr‌​oid/sdk/tools:
```